# Optional for Microsoft.Fade

Tags: jquery

I am converting my HTC file to jquery plugin.

In my HTC file i am using below Microsoft.Fade.

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(duration=0.15,overlap=1.0)
```

It is IE only thing. So i want optional thing for other browsers.

Is there any optional thing for this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fadeOut or fadeIn function:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Answer (score 0):

On jQuery, There are several option to fade.

To certain opacity level, on certain time.

```
$("div").fadeTo(1000, 15);
```

or fade Out completely

```
$("#div").fadeOut(1000);
```

or fade in

```
$("#div").fadeIn(1000);
```